# Vector of object pointers from another vector

Tags: c++

I have

```
std::vector<MyObject> obs;

//fill obs...

std::vector<MyObject*> obsA;
std::vector<MyObject*> obsB;

for (MyObject &p: obs){
    if (p.type == "A"){
        obsA.push_back(p);
    }else{
        obsB.push_back(p);
    }
}
```

where I am trying to create a 2 subsets of some vector of objects. I want the subsets to be pointers, so that any changes made to the object in the obsA or obsB is reflected in the main obs vector. However when I try to run the code I get the following error:

```
src/main.cpp:55:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<MyObject*>::push_back(MyObject&)’
```

I thought that having & after a variable should give the address to that variable, and since obsA and obsB and vector of pointers, that it should be valid to insert an address of a MyObject into there. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: & p is "reference to a p".  You're wanting to push a pointer to p, so use &p.  Now of course this is "dangerous" because std::vector is free to move your p around inside the collection, i.e. if p's are inserted or erased, or the vector allocates new memory and moves all your ps somewhere else.

Comment: The variable you are using to iterate through the vector is a reference. You are not pushing a pointer.

Comment: `p` is a reference.  `obsA.push_back(&p)` is needed to push a pointer.   Bear in mind it is necessary to ensure ALL objects with addresses stored in `obsA` and `obsB` exist as long as the pointers in `obsA` and `obsB` are ever used.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that having & after a variable should give the address to that variable, and since obsA and obsB and vector of pointers, that it should be valid to insert an address of a MyObject into there. What am I doing wrong here?

The most direct answer to your question would be to modify it in the following way. The `p` is just a reference to some element in `obs`. `&p` gives you the *address* in memory to where `p` is referencing, which is what the pointer needs.

```
for (MyObject &p: obs){
    if (p.type == "A"){
        obsA.push_back(&p);
    }else{
        obsB.push_back(&p);
    }
}
```

The bigger question is *why* you are doing it this way. This seems very likely to break and do something bad. Anytime you modify the original vector `obs` (by adding or removing elements), all the pointers in `obsA` and `obsB` can be invalidated (i.e., they no longer point to the right place in `obs`). Changing the size of vector `obs` can cause a memory reallocation and moving the contents of `obs` to a new place in memory, which would be a different location from where the elements of `obsA` and `obsB` are pointing to. Then any further usage of `obsA` or `obsB` would cause undefined behavior, which would lead to abnormal behavior and a likely crash.

There are potential alternatives. For example, replacing the contents of `obs` with `std::shared_ptr<>`s can help, but if you remove one element from `obs` this won't clean it up that element correctly in either `obsA` or `obsB` (i.e., either `obsA` or `obsB` will still hold that object in memory and it won't be deleted correctly). A combination of `std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` could work:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Obj>> obs;
std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Obj>> obsA, obsB;

for (auto p: obs){
    if (p->type == "A"){
        obsA.push_back(p);
    }else{
        obsB.push_back(p);
    }
}

//... later
for( auto it = obsA.begin(); it != obsA.end(); it++ ) {
    if(auto p = (*it).lock()) { // lock tests if the shared_ptr is still valid
        p->otherMemberVariable = "edit"; //This will also edit the same element in the vector obs
    else {
        //the pointer was removed from obs, remove it here too
        it = obsA.erase(it);
    }
}
```

But this is getting very complicated, so you may want to rethink your design a bit.

Comment: Good answer. I recently started using `std::weak_ptr` for something and it was highly satisfying.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
 obsA.push_back(&p);
```

Strongly recommend using shared_ptr rather than raw pointers tho

Comment: if obs changes, so could &p. I feel this needs a mention for completeness (in the absence of shared_ptr).

Comment: If you don't mind, could you give me an example of how to accomplish this more safely with shared_ptr?

Comment: @user3408657 this is not a tutorial site. There are plenty of articles on the net on how to use `shared_ptr`